# PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

As soon as I updated the flutter to version 1.12.13 I found this issue and can't fix it. I did as the firebase_messaging tutorial sent and got the following error:
"error: incompatible types: PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith (registry); "
My code is as follows:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("messages","Messages", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
  NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
  manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

Comment: im getting this error also. any solution as yet ?

Comment: No. I tried and couldn't

Answer (score 115):

Replace this code line:

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
```

with this:

```
FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
```

Make sure to import:

```
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
```

Comment: It worked... just remember to import the class mentioned.

import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

Comment: One important note: if you use different plugins on the flutter side of your background message callback, you also need to add the line "MyPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("package.MyPlugin")); for each used plugin. they won't be added by the GeneratedPluginRegistrant, as it's no longer executed by the background process.

Comment: "registrarFor" is deprecated in latest update. What's the alternative?

Comment: correct! adding some thing to this. not only this FirebaseMessagingPlugin.instead you can use the plugin name that you use in your case.. like android_alarm_manager  or flt_worker.

Comment: If I do this, it keeps installing apk for ever

Answer (score 38):

**Updated on December 31, 2019.**

You should not use the Firebase cloud messaging tool to send notifications, as it forces you to use the title and body.

You must send a notification without the title and body. have the application in the background, that should work for you.

If it works for you, I would appreciate it if you could give me a vote on this answer, thank you.

---

I have found a temporary solution. I am not sure this is the best fix but my plugins work as expected and I assume the problem has to be with the registry provided by io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService on line 164.

**My AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Your Package"> // CHANGE THIS

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="" // YOUR NAME APP
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        <!-- BEGIN: Firebase Cloud Messaging -->    
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        <!-- END: Firebase Cloud Messaging -->    
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**My Application.java**

```
package YOUR PACKAGE HERE;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

**My FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.java**

```
package YOUR PACKAGE HERE;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public final class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant{
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
  }

  private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Send Notification in dart:**

```
Future<void> sendNotificationOnBackground({
  @required String token,
}) async {
  await firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false),
  );
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
    await http.post(
    'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
     headers: <String, String>{
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'key=$SERVERTOKEN', // Constant string
     },
     body: jsonEncode(
     <String, dynamic>{
       'notification': <String, dynamic>{

       },
       'priority': 'high',
       'data': <String, dynamic>{
         'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
         'id': '1',
         'status': 'done',
         'title': 'title from data',
         'message': 'message from data'
       },
       'to': token
     },
    ),
  );
  });  
}
```

I added a wait with a duration of 5 seconds so you can put the application in the background and verify that the message in the background is running

Comment: I tried is your solution but I was unsuccessful, in ONLAUNCH, ONRESUME and ONMESSAGE states appeared, only on ONBACKGROUND not. I put the file FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.java in the same folder as Application.java, was that right? I hope the Flutter team will solve this problem soon. By then I will have to use version 1.9.1, although I want to use 1.12.13 so badly

Comment: Could you create a project and give me the link on your github for me to download and try to run it on my Firebase test project?

Comment: I leave a structure that has helped me send push notifications with dart

Comment: This worked. Not sure why, but it did. Hope the flutter team fixes this in the next release

Comment: where I put the FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.JAVA, in the same folder as the Application or in a firebasemessaging folder? I still couldn't get it to work

Comment: Exactly, you should put it in the folder: => /Android/app/src/java/com.example/Here. If you use kotlin, use Vinicius Zani's answer. I would appreciate it if you valued my answer as a solution, thank you.

Comment: I would also like to know how to add a custom channel

Answer (score 29):

A port of DomingoMG's code to Kotlin can be found below (file paths included).
Tested and working on 10.2020.

/**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
```

/android/app/src/main/kotlin/**Application.kt**

```kotlin
package YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

public class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
  }

  override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
    FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
  }
}
```

/android/app/src/main/kotlin/**FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt**

```kotlin
package YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
  companion object {
    fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
      if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
        return;
      }
      FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
    }

    fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {
      val key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.name
      if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
        return true
      }
      registry.registrarFor(key)
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ``` Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Program type already present: com.example.gf_demo.FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant ```

Comment: I have a 1.17 project which didn't have a MainActivity.java, and no matter how much cludging I did, I could not get my Flutter app to build with `firebase_messaging`. Using this answer, it built right away! Thank you!

Comment: Could you add in which folder the files need to be placed?

Comment: love you man struggled whole day and at last found it

Comment: Now this error occured

Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebase_push_notification_my/com.example.firebase_push_notification_my.Application}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firebase_push_notification_my.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Thank you so much! You've saved me a lot of nerves and time by this. I just couldn't find out why push notifications do not come when an app is closed. Now everything works like a charm

Comment: I've got an error e: D:\Namaa\projects\podcasti_mobile\android\app\src\main\kotlin\Application.kt: (6, 27): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging

Answer (score 9):

Some research and I found this to be working.
Seached up the official Flutterfire repository, and checked out the latest plugins on it.
`GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);` was not working, which is mentioned on the official docs as well. [FlutterFire firebase_messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/).

Using the plugin `io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin`, which I discovered from [Flutterfire GitHub repo](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging) 
 
Currently on firabase_messaging: 9.0.0

```
//
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;
// Be sure to import the exact Plugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
//
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }
 @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
     FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Do

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
```

inplace of

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
```

Comment: add 
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

Comment: Got a message saying it can't cast to FlutterEngine. Solution from Inconnu using "registry.registrarFor() worked."

Comment: This will work for a short time but eventually you will not be able to run your app. I am now getting the error `E/AndroidRuntime(11500): java.lang.ClassCastException: io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry cannot be cast to io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine`

Comment: This solutions is wrong. App will crash by throwing ClassCastException

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DomingoMG's answer, don't forget to remove

```
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
```

from the mainactivity file under the android folder. If not, you will get an error.

Comment: But where I can register my own MethodChannel, when I'll remove configureFlutterEngine?

Comment: According to DomingoMG's answer, FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.java already does the registration of "registerWith..." so that is why configureFlutterEngine is no longer needed. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I understand the FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.java does the registration instead of configureFlutterEngine. But configureFlutterEngine is place where I can register my own MethodChannel to call native API (please see "Writing custom platform-specific code" on flutter.dev). Where can I register MethodChannel when the method configureFlutterEngine is removed?

Comment: I don't have any experience with writing platform-specific code. Sorry that I can't help with that information. I hope you found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I added only water class as extra from the steps in Firebase Messaging package and it was solved  :

```
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
public final class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant{
public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
        return;
    }
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
}

private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work:

```dart
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    // continue with custom method channel registration.
    ...    
}
```

Not sure if you also need to use `cleanUpFlutterEngine` to clean method channel registration.

Answer (score 0):

Change your MainActivity.java file to:
package co.appbrewery.micard;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).