# FlutterEnginePluginRegistry - problem to register plugin Firebase in Flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I can't launch a Flutter project in Android Emulator after upgrade Flutter. I obtain the following message in the debug console:

`W/FlutterEnginePluginRegistry( 7750): Attempted to register plugin (io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry$ShimRegistrarAggregate@75e268b) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@d56f368).`

It worked fine before Flutter upgrade. I detected that the problem is with Firebase plugins. I created a new empty Flutter project and it works ok. After add firebase_auth plugin, I obtain the above messge again.

I tried to clean the project, different Firebase versions, restart and create new emulators, ...

My flutter version:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.5-pre.28, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.17763.973], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.14.5-pre.28 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 93a5b7d419 (2 hours ago), 2020-01-25 01:23:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 4218f8026f
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

And my pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1
```

Has anyone had this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446933/pluginregistry-cannot-be-converted-to-flutterengine/59490722#59490722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output of flutter doctor, you are using the master channel.

From the documentation:

> **master**
>
> The current tip-of-tree, absolute latest cutting edge build. Usually functional, though sometimes we accidentally break things.

Therefore you might have some issues, and it seems [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49481) is one of them.

---

You can use the `stable` channel for now:

> **stable**
>
> When we believe we have a particularly good build, we promote it to the stable channel. We intend to do this more or less every quarter, but this may vary. We recommend that you use this channel for all production app releases. We may ship hotfixes to the stable channel for high-priority bugs, although our intent is to do this rarely.

Latest version released was `v1.12.13+hotfix.5`

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

You can switch channel by executing:

```
flutter channel stable
```

Comment: Stil have this problem with Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)

Comment: Also on v1.17.5 stable

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem neither explain it, more like a general recommendation like "try restarting your PC". Having same problem after updating to 1.22.2 and yes, 'stable' chan

Answer (score 0):

I have also get these problems after updating this but i solved this problesm using both these commands

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter packages get

Comment: Same solution as Peter Haddad ' s. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.

Deleting "AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);" in Application's onCreate
fixed it for me.