# PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine in background notifications firebase_messaging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I was about to create App with handling notifications(Firebase Messaging) in background. I followed the tutorial given in the official [Docs](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#optionally-handle-background-messages). I was getting error while building the app

[image: Error]

Even I tried the solution give in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446933/pluginregistry-cannot-be-converted-to-flutterengine) in stackoverflow, that has no effect because i had many other plugins to be registered for android automatically, they were not working

`flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Linux, locale en_IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
```

**FCM api version***

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'
```

Help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

My English isn't so good so feel free to ask me if there is anything unclear.

I solved this problem by this code

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {        
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry as FlutterEngine)
}
```

I don't know why Because I don't search detail.
In my case, this work for me.

I'm happy if it helps for you.