# flutter -i get error when i want to set background task (PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine ...)

Tags: android, flutter, location, hybrid-mobile-app

i want to set a background location tracker for that i use the location_background plugin and follow the steps in [background location wiki](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/wiki/Background-Location-Updates) 
but when i run build task i get this error :

> /home/walid/Desktop/covid19/covid19/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/covid19/Application.java:17:
>   error: incompatible types: PluginRegistry cannot be converted to
>   FlutterEngine GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry); ^
>   Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with
>   -Xdiags:verbose to get full output 1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler
>   error output for details.
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4m 52s

the Application.java code :

```
package com.example.app;

import com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class Application  extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocationPlugin.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

android SDK 28
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8

Comment: did you try searching the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446933/pluginregistry-cannot-be-converted-to-flutterengine

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem and just fixed it using following code (firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1)

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }

}
```