# How to implement push notification with flutter embedding v2 in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, push-notification

**Console Log**

```
    /Users/heermi/Flutter/Secure Home Project/Secure Home Repo/secure-home/android/app/src/main/java/com/k8sllc/securehome/MainActivity.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine);
  symbol:   variable FlutterEngine
  location: class MainActivity
/Users/heermi/Flutter/Secure Home Project/Secure Home Repo/secure-home/android/app/src/main/java/com/k8sllc/securehome/MainActivity.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    methodChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(),CHANNEL);
  symbol:   method getFlutterView()
  location: class MainActivity
/Users/heermi/Flutter/Secure Home Project/Secure Home Repo/secure-home/android/app/src/main/java/com/k8sllc/securehome/MainActivity.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
  symbol:   method getFlutterView()
  location: class MainActivity
Note: /Users/heermi/Flutter/Secure Home Project/Secure Home Repo/secure-home/android/app/src/main/java/com/k8sllc/securehome/FireBaseMessagingService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.k8sllc.securehome">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    tools:replace="android:label"    
    android:name=".BaseApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:label="Lok">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="test_key” />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.license"
        android:value="test_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"
        android:value="test_pass” />

    <service
        android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.TrackingService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.transistorsoft.locationmanager.service.LocationRequestService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
    
    <!-- Add this content for push notification -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="Lok" />
    <service android:name=".FireBaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FireBaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>    

</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.k8sllc.securehome;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  public static MethodChannel methodChannel;
  private String CHANNEL = "com.k8sllc.securedhome/platform_channel";
  private static final String TAG1 = "MainActivity";
  Intent intent;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine);
    methodChannel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(),CHANNEL);
    Log.e(TAG1, "onCreate: " );

    //Intent which we are passing in android will be used here to make json and then send it flutter application. Okay?yes

    intent = getIntent();
    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            (call, result) -> {
              if (call.method.equals("getIntent")) {
                if (intent != null) {             
                  JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                      userDetails.put("data", intent.getStringExtra("data"));                
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                         Log.v(TAG, "onError: " + e);
                      }
                      result.success(userDetails.toString());
                  }  else {
                  android.util.Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: No Intent" );
                  result.success("false");
                }
              } else {
                result.notImplemented();
              }
            }
          );
        }


  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e(TAG1, "onStart: "+getIntent().hasExtra("type") );
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG1, "onResume: "+getIntent().hasExtra("type")  );
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent != null) {
      JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();
          try {
            userDetails.put("data", intent.getStringExtra("data"));
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                MainActivity.methodChannel.invokeMethod("notification", userDetails.toString());
              }
            });
          } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.v(TAG, "onError: " + e);
          }
        }
    }

  private void cancelAllNotifications() {
//    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
  }
}
```

Flutter doctor summary

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Here I have attached all that I did. Could anyone please help me with this?
Here I have attached console log and AndroidManifest.XML snippet to understand it better.
I have added MainActivity.java file snippet for the push notification idea what I have done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446933/pluginregistry-cannot-be-converted-to-flutterengine

Comment: I already tried this solution, still getting the same error.