# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging onBackgroundMessage

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to register Firebase Cloud Messaging to run it in the background and receive notifications.

**Problem Statement:**
The application is working fine and receives notification and data on the following States without exception.

1. onMessage
2. onLaunch
3. onResume

4.**onBackgroundMessage** - when i introduce state **onBackgroundMessage** for handling notification in background then it throws expectation and while receiving notification application crashes on **onBackgroundMessage**.

I have looked into different StackOverflow questions. One of which from where I was able to take kotlin code.

1. [PluginRegistry cannot be converted to FlutterEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446933/pluginregistry-cannot-be-converted-to-flutterengine)

But it gives me this error I am unable to understand the error and how to resolve it.

**Exception (In Fluter Console)**

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516): Failed to handle method calls
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516): java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:693)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 8516):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter ( 8516): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, PluginRegistrantCallback is not set., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/flutter ( 8516):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:174)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:693)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/flutter ( 8516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter ( 8516): )
E/flutter ( 8516): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
E/flutter ( 8516): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8516): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter ( 8516): #3      FirebaseMessaging.configure (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:126:16)
E/flutter ( 8516): #4      PushNotificationsManager.init (package:flutter_app/services/pushNotification.dart:15:26)
E/flutter ( 8516): #5      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:flutter_app/main.dart:39:30)
E/flutter ( 8516): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4812:57)
E/flutter ( 8516): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6164:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4700:16)
E/flutter ( 8516): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4369:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4654:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6164:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6164:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4700:16)
E/flutter ( 8516): #26     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4847:11)
E/flutter ( 8516): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4369:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4654:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #29     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:11)
E/flutter ( 8516): #30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:5)
E/flutter ( 8516): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
E/flutter ( 8516): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
E/flutter ( 8516): #33
I/flutter ( 8516): [SECRET TOKEN]
```

### Code and Configurations below

**Code Flutter Side**

```
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch: $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume: $message");
        },
      );


//Static Function

Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("################## ON BACKGROUND - APP IS RUNNING ON BACKGROUND  ###################");
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt** [ app/src/kotlin/com/example/flutter_app/MainActivity.kt ]

```
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

**Application Level** bulid.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
}
```

**Project Level** bulid.gradle

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
         ...
         ...
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

** Flutter Doctor **

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-2.0.pre.52, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```